# Вывод thumbnail записи со стороннего сайта

Tags: wordpress

Нужно вывести 2 последние новости из стороннего блога.

Title и краткое описание вывожу, а вот картинку новости не получается вывести. Есть ли способ достичь желаемого?

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://ссылка на сайт/feed/'); 
$feed->set_item_limit(2);                       
$feed->init();                                  
$feed->handle_content_type();

foreach( $feed->get_items(0, 2) as $item ){
?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="rss_item">
            <a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a>
            <p><?php echo $item-> get_description(); ?> </p>
            <a class="hidden_link" href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">Читать далее</a>                                        
        </div>                                              
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, какой массив возвращает $item->get_enclosures()

Comment: @KAGGDesign Array
(
    [0] => SimplePie_Enclosure Object
        (    
           ...
            [thumbnails] => 
           ...
        )
)   Но запись foreach ($item->get_enclosures() as $enclosure)
        {
         echo $enclosure->get_thumbnails();
        } не хочет работать

Comment: трудно так сказать, отладчиком в phpStrom надо копнуть. Сейчас попробую

Comment: посмотрел. код ошибок не выдает, читает блог моего основного сайта, но $item->get_enclosures() возвращает одно пустое $enclosure (все поля null ) и $enclosure->get_thumbnails() возвращает null. Похоже, дело не в коде, а в данных...

Comment: так конечно - https://kagg.eu/feed/ - этот xml не содержит никаких картинок

Comment: В документации к SimplePie есть такая инструкция: if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure())
 {
  foreach ((array) $enclosure->get_thumbnails() as $thumbnail)
  {
   echo $thumbnail;
  }
 } Но откуда они берут картинки?

Comment: вы глазами свой feed просмотрите - если в нем нет картинок, никакой код не поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ отрицательный, к сожалению. Если сайт сторонний, сделать этого нельзя.

WordPress формирует свой feed в файле `wp-includes/feed-rss2.php`. В нём нет никаких инструкций, которые бы выводили картинку записи (thumbnail). А в объекте SimplePie, кторым вы пользуетесь, нет никаких методов доступа к thumbnail, даже если бы она была включена в вывод поста по feed.

Другое дело, если есть доступ к этому стороннему блогу. Тогда, пользуясь этой [инструкцией](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds), можно скопировать файл `wp-includes/feed-rss2.php` в свою тему и добавить в него вывод картинки, обернув ее в некий тег xml. (Ни к коем случае не стоит править файл в ядре!).

Правда, поскольку в SimplePie методов нет для обработки картинки, придется весь xml поста получать в строку через `get_raw_data()` и парсить ее самостоятельно, чтобы вытащить оттуда тег с картинкой внутри.

Другой вариант - надо на стороннем сайте каждому посту добавить поле 'enclosure' и в это поле поместить, например, url картинки поста. Тогда метод `get_enclosure()` в SimplePie вернет эти вложения.